# syntax of the regex language used by ctest -R

Tags: cmake, ctest

As specified on
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/ctest.1.html,
ctest supports filtering tests to run by regex. Unfortunately I can't seem to find out what syntax the regex language used by ctest has.

I'd like to do something like

```html
ctest -R "SomeTest|SomeOtherTest" # should execute the two tests named and no other tests.
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was calling ctest the wrong way. The way i was wrapping it in a bash script I had to escape the pipe as `\\\|`.